# Sent value and show output when select tag change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I new in term of using jQuery.

I practice using native php ajax, but for this time I need to learn jQuery for the current technology and demand.

I sent "types" value method POST to other page (ajaxInfo.php) when the  tag change.

After the select tag change, it should show the result at `<div id="showList">` that come from database (MySQL). But nothing happen.

Below are the source code.

Body

```
<select id="form-types" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" name="types">
    <option value="">PLEASE CHOSE</option>
    <option value="STATE">STATE</option>
    <option value="FACULTY">FACULTY</option>
    <option value="PROGRAME">PROGRAME</option>
</select>

<div id="showList"></div>
```

jQuery AJAX

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("select#form-types").change(function () {
    var types = $("select#form-types").val();
    if (types != null) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'ajaxInfo.php',
          data: "types=" + types,
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function (response) {
            $("#showList").html(response);
          }
        }
      });
  });
}); 
</script>
```

Post Page (ajaxInfo.php)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["types"]) === TRUE){
    $types = $_POST["types"];
}
else{
    $types = null;
}
include '../dbco.php';
$query = $dbc -> query ("SELECT child FROM infobase WHERE parent='$types'");
if ($query -> num_rows > 0){
    echo "LIST OF : " . $types . "REGISTERED<br />";
    $count = 1;
    while ($result = $query -> fetch_assoc()){
        echo "$count" . $result['child'] . "<br />";
        count++;
    }
}else{
    echo "NO " . $types . " REGISTERED";
}
?>
```

Thank You.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: @MehdiBounya - After the select tag change, it should show the result at <div id="showList"> that come from database (MySQL). But nothing happen.

Comment: You shouldn't make your queries that way

Comment: Check the console and tell me is there any errors or what is the value returned by show.php

Comment: @Gerardo - then how is the good way?

Comment: @MehdiBounya - How?

Comment: From the inspecting tool choose the console tab

Comment: @MehdiBounya - Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. Acording to this error, the error is come  if (types!= null) statement at the close bracket

Comment: @Asyraf Read this... [PHP: SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @Gerardo i use this [link]https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp[\link] for SQL prevention.

Comment: @Asyraf I read it and that's just for XSS (Cross Site Scripting) not the same as SQL Injections. You don't have to listen to me it's just a recommendation. You could read about prepared statements, they're pretty easy to use.

Comment: @Gerardo oh, thanks for the recommendation. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You are using id (form-types) for your select input field. but your are tying to targeting another id (form-jenis).

use same named id for select input field and in your jquery selector.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#form-types").change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var types= $("select#form-types").val();

        if (types!= null)
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'show.php',
            data: "types=" + types,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) 
            {
                $("#showList").html(response);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing bracket

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select#form-types").change(function(){

                var types= $("select#form-types").val();

                if (types!= null)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'ajaxInfo.php',
                    data: "types=" + types,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(response) 
                    {
                        $("#showList").html(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
}); // add this
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my ajax jQuery function do not have close pair, so i decide to add it and it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#form-types").change(function(){

            var types= $("select#form-types").val();

            if (types!= null)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'ajaxInfo.php',
                    data: "types=" + types,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(response) 
                    {
                        $("#showList").html(response);
                    }
                }); // Add This
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

After the code running good, i also found out the error at ajaxInfo.php, the count inside the loop missing $ symbol

```
if ($query -> num_rows > 0)
{
    echo "LIST OF : " . $types . "REGISTERED<br />";

    $count = 1;

    while ($result = $query -> fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "$count" . $result['child'] . "<br />";
        $count++; //HERE
    }
}
```

Thanks for the people that help.